# SQL Server works slow after enable XP_CMDShell even disable until restart service

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2017, functions, xp-cmdshell

2 days ago I created a function that needs `INSERT` and `UPDATE`, and I enabled `XP_CMDShell` and do it by running a script.

Afterwards, SQL Server works very slow for `SELECT` commands. Even very simple `SELECT` statement that runs after `INSERT` via separated command.

I tested this behaviour on other databases and it giae same result that `SELECT` runs after some minutes.

Also, I tested it on 2 other hosts with SQL Server 2014 and the result was the same.

Function that I created to get value of it within another select statement:

```
ALTER FUNCTION [Prg].[intCheckDelayedProcessProgram] 
(
     @SalesOrderProductID INT,
     @MainProductTreeID INT,
     @ProductTreeID INT,
     @ProcessId INT,
     @additionalDays INT = 2,
     @currentDateReverceString VARCHAR(10) = NULL
)
RETURNS INT
AS
BEGIN
    --declare @SalesOrderProductID INT = 40957,
    --  @MainProductTreeID INT = 93758,
    --  @ProductTreeID INT = 93758,
    --  @ProcessId INT = 4472,
    --  @additionalDays INT = 2,
    --  @currentDateReverceString VARCHAR(10) = null -- '30/09/1398'

DECLARE @ProduceDailyProgramProductTree_Id INT, @ProgramQuantity INT, @startDate JalaliDate,
        @CurrentDate JalaliDate, @lastDate JalaliDate, @additionalDate JalaliDate, @holiDaysCount INT;
IF(@currentDateReverceString IS NULL OR @currentDateReverceString = '')
    SET @CurrentDate = dbo.GetCurrentJalaliDate();
ELSE
    SET @CurrentDate = Gnr.RevercePersianDate(@currentDateReverceString);

IF (@additionalDays IS NULL)
    SET @additionalDays = 2;

DECLARE @allDelayedItemsCount INT = 0;
BEGIN
    DECLARE @sql NVARCHAR(4000), @cmd VARCHAR(4000);
    DECLARE cursor_pdppt CURSOR
        FOR SELECT pdppt.ID, pdppt.ProgramQuantity, pdppt.[Date] FROM Prg.ProduceDailyProgramProductTree pdppt
        WHERE pdppt.SalesOrderProductID = @SalesOrderProductID
                AND pdppt.MainProductTreeID = @MainProductTreeID
                AND pdppt.ProductTreeID = @ProductTreeID
                AND pdppt.Process = @ProcessId
                AND ISNULL(pdppt.IsDelayed, 0) = 0
    OPEN cursor_pdppt;
    FETCH NEXT FROM cursor_pdppt INTO @ProduceDailyProgramProductTree_Id, @ProgramQuantity, @startDate;
    WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
        BEGIN
            SET @lastDate = Gnr.RevercePersianDate([Prg].[intGetLastDateForDelayedProcessProgram](@startDate, @additionalDays, @CurrentDate, 1));
            IF (@CurrentDate.GetDate() > @lastDate.GetDate())
            BEGIN
                IF ((SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Prg.ProduceDailyOperation pdo WHERE pdo.ProduceDailyProgramProductTreeID = @ProduceDailyProgramProductTree_Id AND pdo.Process = @ProcessId
                        AND pdo.[Date].GetDate() > @lastDate.GetDate()) = 0)
                BEGIN
                    SET @allDelayedItemsCount = @allDelayedItemsCount + @ProgramQuantity;
                END
                ELSE
                BEGIN
                    SET @allDelayedItemsCount = @allDelayedItemsCount +
                        (@ProgramQuantity - 
                            (SELECT SUM(pdo.ProducedQuantity) FROM Prg.ProduceDailyOperation pdo 
                                WHERE pdo.ProduceDailyProgramProductTreeID = @ProduceDailyProgramProductTree_Id 
                                    AND pdo.Process = @ProcessId AND pdo.[Date].GetDate() <= @lastDate.GetDate()));
                END;

                SELECT @sql = 'UPDATE [Prg].[ProduceDailyProgramProductTree] SET [IsDelayed] = 1 WHERE ID = ' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), @ProduceDailyProgramProductTree_Id);
                SELECT @cmd = 'sqlcmd -S ' + @@SERVERNAME + ' -d ' + DB_NAME() + ' -Q "' + @sql + '"'
                EXEC MASTER..XP_CMDSHELL @cmd , 'no_output'
            END;
            FETCH NEXT FROM cursor_pdppt INTO @ProduceDailyProgramProductTree_Id, @ProgramQuantity, @startDate;
        END;
    CLOSE cursor_pdppt;

    IF (@allDelayedItemsCount > 0)
    BEGIN
        IF (EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM Prg.ProduceDailyProgramProductTreeDelayed pdppt
                        WHERE pdppt.SalesOrderProductID = @SalesOrderProductID
                            AND pdppt.MainProductTreeID = @MainProductTreeID
                            AND pdppt.ProductTreeID = @ProductTreeID
                            AND pdppt.Process = @ProcessId))
        BEGIN
            SELECT @allDelayedItemsCount = @allDelayedItemsCount 
                + (SELECT pdpptd.DelayedQuantity FROM Prg.ProduceDailyProgramProductTreeDelayed pdpptd
                    WHERE pdpptd.SalesOrderProductID = @SalesOrderProductID
                        AND pdpptd.MainProductTreeID = @MainProductTreeID
                        AND pdpptd.ProductTreeID = @ProductTreeID
                        AND pdpptd.Process = @ProcessId
                        AND ISNULL(pdpptd.Active, 0) = 1
                        AND ISNULL(pdpptd.IsDeleted, 0) = 0);

            SELECT @sql = 'UPDATE [Prg].[ProduceDailyProgramProductTreeDelayed] SET DelayedQuantity = ' 
                                + CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), @allDelayedItemsCount) + 'WHERE SalesOrderProductID = ' 
                                + CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), @SalesOrderProductID) + 'AND MainProductTreeID = ' 
                                + CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), @MainProductTreeID) + 'AND ProductTreeID = ' 
                                + CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), @ProductTreeID) + 'AND Process = ' 
                                + CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), @ProcessId) +';';
        END
        ELSE
        BEGIN
            SELECT @sql = 'INSERT INTO [Prg].[ProduceDailyProgramProductTreeDelayed] (SalesOrderProductID, MainProductTreeID, Process, ProductTreeID, DelayedQuantity, Active, IsDeleted) VALUES ('
                     + CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), @SalesOrderProductID) + ', ' 
                     + CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), @MainProductTreeID) + ', '
                     + CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), @ProcessId) + ', '
                     + CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), @ProductTreeID) + ', '
                     + CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), @allDelayedItemsCount) + ', ''1'', ''0'')';
        END;

        SELECT @cmd = 'sqlcmd -S ' + @@SERVERNAME + ' -d ' + DB_NAME() + ' -Q "' + @sql + '"'
        EXEC MASTER..XP_CMDSHELL @cmd , 'no_output'
    END
    ELSE
    IF(EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM Prg.ProduceDailyProgramProductTreeDelayed pdpptd
            WHERE pdpptd.SalesOrderProductID = @SalesOrderProductID
            AND pdpptd.MainProductTreeID = @MainProductTreeID
            AND pdpptd.ProductTreeID = @ProductTreeID
            AND pdpptd.Process = @ProcessId
            AND ISNULL(pdpptd.Active, 0) = 1
            AND ISNULL(pdpptd.IsDeleted, 0) = 0))
    BEGIN
        SELECT @allDelayedItemsCount = 
                (SELECT pdpptd.DelayedQuantity FROM Prg.ProduceDailyProgramProductTreeDelayed pdpptd
                    WHERE pdpptd.SalesOrderProductID = @SalesOrderProductID
                        AND pdpptd.MainProductTreeID = @MainProductTreeID
                        AND pdpptd.ProductTreeID = @ProductTreeID
                        AND pdpptd.Process = @ProcessId
                        AND ISNULL(pdpptd.Active, 0) = 1
                        AND ISNULL(pdpptd.IsDeleted, 0) = 0);
    END;
END;
RETURN @allDelayedItemsCount;
END
```

`JalaliDate` is user defined type to hold persian date time by Assembly.

`Gnr.RevercePersianDate` function to convert string persian date to JalaliDate.
`[Prg].[intGetLastDateForDelayedProcessProgram]` other function to calculate specified date by Holidays that I think dose not issue.

**UPDATE 1**

I test function codes by pass parameter values by inline declare and set test values. Then, user Sql Server Profiler to check script of function, that see scripts stops on this line `SET @CurrentDate = dbo.GetCurrentJalaliDate()` that use function of Assembly. Execution running without any error and not responding!! Note: I test `SELECT dbo.GetCurrentJalaliDate()` that responding very fast without error!

**UPDATE 2**

I call function `[Prg].[intCheckDelayedProcessProgram]` within `SP` and inside a complex `SELECT` statement, that can't call `SP` in `select`, so just solution for me was define function.
Code run in local server that is together with all data and other SP and functions.
If there is alternative for `CURSOR` help me to rewrite function with it.

Comment: That's certainly an approach. I'm curious about your decision to use xp_cmdshell to invoke sqlcmd. Is there a reason you did that instead of directly inserting/updating the table?

Comment: Great - [same person, same question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59409553/sql-server-works-slow-after-enable-xp-cmdshell-even-disable-until-restart-servic), different user.

Comment: Trying to use tricks likes this (and there are others, even worse) to get around the Function isolation restrictions is a very bad idea. Those restrictions exist for several very good reasons, and one of those reasons is potential locking problems. Those problems are made much worse by spawning an external process and trying to have it do the dirty work for you. It can cause, not just blocking and deadlock issues, but irresolvable ones. I would recommend starting with sp_lock while the problem is happening to see what is waiting on what, But there are other problems with this as well.

Comment: You should also post the code from the `CurrentJalaliDate()` function as well. And probably the code that is calling your SQL Function also.

Comment: Scalar UDFs can cause problems. See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/user-defined-functions/scalar-udf-inlining?view=sql-server-ver15#performance-of-scalar-udfs. That topic's Performance concerns apply to earlier versions of SQL Server. Instead of a scalar function, consider a Table Valued Function, or in-line the scalar function's T-SQL. To see the function calls, you need to trace the SP:StmtStarting event. A large number of events can be fired, quickly. That means you may need to quickly stop tracing!

Comment: @RBarryYoung okay, now I simply have to know! What are the other, even worse tricks?

Comment: @AlexFriedman OpenRowset related stuff and CLR externalizations are some.  Both can be used in a similar way, create processes outside of SQLServer and then re-enter the same SQLServer to do DML or even DDL stuff from a user-defined function.  CLR has some protections to try to prevent things like this, but they can be overridden or evaded.   There is some even sketchier things out there.  One of the things that makes them worse is how obtuse and concealed they are.  At least with `XP_CMDSHELL` you can see what's being done.

Answer (score 10):

Instead of using `xp_cmdshell` to execute queries against SQL Server, change your code to use [stored procedures](https://learn.microsoft.com/sql/relational-databases/stored-procedures/create-a-stored-procedure), [user-defined functions](https://learn.microsoft.com/sql/relational-databases/user-defined-functions/create-user-defined-functions-database-engine), or even [dynamic T-SQL](https://learn.microsoft.com/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/sp-executesql-transact-sql) called using `sp_executesql`. If you need to execute code against a different server, use a [linked server](https://learn.microsoft.com/sql/relational-databases/linked-servers/create-linked-servers-sql-server-database-engine).

Finally, consider rewriting your code not to use a cursor if possible. Set-based operations in SQL Server are far more efficient.

Since these topics are all extremely in-depth topics on their own, there is no way I can flesh out an answer here, but I hope these links help. Good luck.

Comment: Hi @Randolph, thank you for your reply. I edit question and add `Update 2`. Please read it.

Comment: See the comments on your question, and see the other answer(s), as there is some good advice there. Consider using table-valued functions (TVFs) to get around the issues you're seeing.

Answer (score 3):

You should definitely find a better way than doing DML through a function. You don't need to attach this process to a `SELECT` statement. You can just dump the results of the query to a temp table and use a CURSOR to iterate over that (just like you are doing in this function), calling a stored procedure to do what you are currently doing in this function.

However, *at the very least*, you should add some options to your cursor so that they don't lock the base table(s):

```sql
DECLARE cursor_pdppt CURSOR LOCAL STATIC READ_ONLY FORWARD_ONLY
        FOR ...
```

And, immediately after the `CLOSE cursor_pdppt;`, you should add:

```sql
DEALLOCATE cursor_pdppt;
```